# Bootstrap grid layout is not working?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I don't know where I am missing something, but grid system is not working at all. I am using firefox. Is there any problem with require_once or well?
Here is index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Study Surge</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php require_once('navbar.php');?>
    <?php require_once('home.html'); ?>




    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is home.html:

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="well engineering">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img src="image/engiico.gif">
                    <h1>Engineering</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="well engineering">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img src="image/engiico.gif">
                    <h1>Engineering</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The overall result gives:
[image: the image of home page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. Both of your columns are wrapped in row elements, which clear the floated column divs.
2. Is the path to your css file correct?  If it is in a 'css' folder, you probably want:

   ```
   <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   ```

Same would go for your bootstrap javascript file.

Also, you probably want to take another look at the bootstrap grid system:  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

The 'container' class would probably be the outermost element.  Only columns can be immediate children of rows.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 engineering well">
            <img src="xyz" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
             <img src="xyz" />
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +for Only columns can be immediate children of rows.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a parent div surrounding each grid-item. Divs are block elements by default so they will take up 100% of their parent's width. When you wrap a grid element with a div, the grid will work but only on that element. You need to re-write the grid to something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="well engineering">
    <img src="image/engiico.gif">
      <h1>Engineering</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you could do:

```
<div class="col-md-3 well engineering">
  <img src="image/engiico.gif">
  <h1>Engineering</h1>
</div>
```

With the 2nd solution, make sure .well or .engineering don't modify margins or width since that will break the grid.